# use headset microphone instead of device microphone

Tags: android

I have created a broadcast application which uses microphone and camera for live broadcast,
The microphone is working well about when I attach a headset on it,
Bluetooth or Wired then I try to speak using headset microphone it doesn't recognize the microphone but in the device microphone it recognize which I dont want cause what I want is to recognize the headset microphone,

Well this is what I try so far and about the audio in headset there is no problem it is working well.

```
private void audioManagerCheck(){
    AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    int audioType = getAudioType();

    if (myAudioManager == null || BCSocket.getInstance().audioType == audioType) {
        return;
    }

    switch (audioType) {
        // Speaker
        case 1:
            myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            myAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            myAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
            break;
        // Wire ear phone
        case 2:
            myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            myAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            myAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            break;
        // Bluetooth ear phone
        case 3:
            myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            myAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            myAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems OK and I think the problem is elsewhere. How do you start the Recording procedure? Maybe you're using a wrong device (built-in Mic instead of the normal Mic) when recording...

Comment: @emandt I uses a broadcast library for it. https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-wowza-gocoder-video-broadcasting-android-app, I tried different devices still same result

Comment: If you're using this kind of big library why do you need to setup manually the BluetoothSCO?, the "setMode()", etc...? That library should do this for you especially because you should be able to choose which InputSource to use for recording. There is no-sense to create a big library like that and let the use do boring work OUTSIDE it (setting the Mode, disable the Speaker, etc..). Maybe you missed some library parameter/configuration.

Comment: @emandt this library doesn't setup it automatically it become a bug which why I modify it manually even the headset sound wont work without adding method audioManagerCheck, it uses the device sound and microphone by default